# Updating an unsigned INT fails with low values on MySQL

Tags: mysql, unsigned-integer, on-duplicate-key

I have a table with a composite primary key (a, b) where I want to update multiple columns with the syntax INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE.

```
INSERT INTO table_a (a, b, c, d, e) VALUES (1533571200, 1, 7, 1, -1) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  c = c + 7, d = d + 1, e = e - 1;
```

This is working perfectly for all columns except for the one with with an UNSIGNED value (column e).

Granted that the equation e - 1 always yields to a number greater than 0 and less than 100, is it possible that the query execution tries the INSERT statement independently of the DUPLICATE KEY check ?

If yes, is there some piece of documentation that specifically addresses this issue or provide some rationale around that ?

Comment: What is `equation e + -1 ` ?? And how is always greater than 0?

Comment: `is working perfectly` so what is the error?

Comment: The error is 1264 Out of range value for column 'e'

Comment: By working perfectly I meant that this is circumscribed to this column

Comment: The equation e + -1 is always greater than 0 given the data in the table and the statements I am trying

Comment: `VALUES (1533571200, 1, 7, 1, -1) ` but `e` is `-1` here and `-1 + (-1)` is `-2` what Im missing?

Comment: e is the current value of the colum, e.g 10.

Comment: But you are inserting `-1`?

Comment: Yes, but because there is a match in the key, I would have thought that the insert statement would not have been evaluated and instead that only the UPDATE one would be executed. But apparently not - I'm trying to wrap my head around that.

Comment: [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain the range of values your application expects for column `e`, and please explain in more detail what you are trying to do.We know an unsigned int has the range [`0`, `4 294 967 295`], but we don't know what your particular application's range is. It's pretty obvious the `INSERT` part of your SQL statement tries to put `-1` into an unsigned value. That will never work.  Also, try ` ... e = e -1` instead of the slightly more complex `e = e + -1`.

Comment: @O.Jones I updated the application values. I get that inserting -1 in an unsigned column won't work. What I don't understand is why it won't work even if the INSERT part of the statement never gets executed (if there is a match on the key AND e - 1 >= 0)

Comment: So if you use `INSERT INTO tableA (a, b, c, d, e) VALUES (1533571200, 1, 7, 1, 25) ` the update works?

Comment: Yes it works. It really looks like the engine first try to parse / evaluate the INSERT part. There is not much details on that in the MySQL doc https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` form of `INSERT` actually attempts the insert operation. Only when the insert encounters the duplicate key does it switch over to `UPDATE`.

One might think that the query planner could somehow detect the duplicate key without attempting the insert.  But it doesn't, and indeed probably couldn't, in all cases.

One could imagine an `INSERT ... ON ERROR UPDATE ...` statement. But that statement doesn't exist.

That explains why a datatype conversion error in the `INSERT` makes the whole query fail.

Comment: I think the query planner could detect the duplicate key before throwing an error. Disabling the strict_mode allows the update to occur and the error is toned down to a warning.